# Is there a limit on how much the JSON binary response from Get Blob Data API can hold?

Tags: rest-api, attachment, blob

Refer to this documentation: [Get Blob Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm), the response of that API is binary.

> Document body content is returned in binary form. The response content type isn’t JSON or XML since the returned data is binary. You can save the returned binary data to a file to store and access it.

API:
GET

```
curl https://MyDomainName.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/Attachment/015D0000000N3ZZIA0/body -H "Authorization: Bearer token"
```

Response:

```
�PNG


IHXXX...
```

Is there a limit on **how much the maximum binary string** can hold in the response?